# Golang parse a json with DYNAMIC key

Tags: go

I have a json string as follows:

```
j := `{"bvu62fu6dq": {
           "name": "john",
           "age": 23,
           "xyz": "weu33s"
           .....
           .....}
      }`
```

I want to extract the value of `name` and `age` from above json string. I looked at this example given at golang site http://play.golang.org/p/YQgzP7KPp9

But my problem is the key in the json on top level is dynamic. That means `bvu62fu6dq` is dynamic. I have created struct like this:

```
 type Info struct {
   UniqueID map[string]string
 }
```

But not sure how to extract `name` and `age`. My code is at http://play.golang.org/p/Vbdkd3XIKc

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

type Info map[string]Person
```

Then, after decoding this works:

```
fmt.Printf("%s: %d\n", info["bvu62fu6dq"].Name, info["bvu62fu6dq"].Age)
```

Full example: http://play.golang.org/p/FyH-cDp3Na

Comment: As I said, my key is dynamic and It wont be always `bvu62fu6dq` therefore I cannot use `info["bvu62fu6dq"].Name`

Comment: Sure, and info is a normal map. You can iterate over all keys or access any specific key, as usual for maps

Comment: @JVK How to do this if there are other keys parallel to bvu62fu6dq. 
e.g  {"bvu62fu6dq": {
           "name": "john",
           "age": 23,
          },
    "city": "NJ"
      }`